# How do I fix this JFrame resize "bug"?

Tags: java

I made A gui that is (640+200)x640 pixels big. On the left side is a chess board (it is at position 0,0 and has a size of 640x640.The 200 pixels on additional width are ment for some buttons to configure the game etc.

The problem:

The chess board's dimensions always have to be multiples of 8 to fit the frame perfectly. If i resize the frame a little bit so that its height increases by 7 pixels, there is a little gap between the chess board and the frame because the squares can't ne drawn in euqal size.

What is a clever way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Swing or AWT, using `Frame` or `JFrame` or `Window` or `JWindow` as the window you're working in.

Step 1) Put your chessboard into its own `JPanel`. Let's call that class `ChessBoardPanel`.

Step 2) Set the `ChessBoardPanel`'s minimum, preferred and maximum sizes to the sizes you wish for in its constructor (or put it in a method if you wanna check the resize event of the parent and react to that, adjusting in 8px steps for bigger/smaller parent window.)

Step 3) Install a LayoutManager in the Window (`window.setLayout(...)`), like `BoderLayout`

Step 4) Create a new instance of the `ChessBoardPanel`: `ChessBoardPanel myChessBoardPanel = new ChessBoardPanel(parentWindow)`;

Step 5) Add it to the parent window, maybe indicating layout behavior. For example, if you went with the `BorderLayout`, add it like this in the parent window: `this.add(myChessBoardPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);` so it will always be displayed on the left.